# Java remote code Hot Swap

Tags: java, remote-debugging, remote-server, hotswap

I have a java project (spring+hibernate) and build in via maven. It's to big to run it on localhost and I run it at VPS. Are exist any technologies for remote code hotswap?

Comment: Careful... You are directly asking for an off-site ressource! This can and will get flagged! Show what you have tried/researched instead!

Comment: I have tried to use jrebel, but it's not free. Also i have tried spring-loaded, but I cannot run it remotely with intellij idea.

Answer (score 2):

Look at https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm over JDWP + HotswapAgent https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent